# Modal is not opening through OnClick function in Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, modal-dialog, fullcalendar

I am trying to open a Modal which will allow me to add an Event to my fullcalendar, but the Modal is not opening throught OnClick() = {() => setModalOpen(true)}

Help me im stuck

Here is the AddEventModal Component code (the modal i am trying to open):

```
const AddEventModal = (isOpen, onClose, onEventAdded) => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [start, setStart] = useState(new Date());
    const [end, setEnd] = useState(new Date());

    const onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        onEventAdded({
            title,
            start,
            end
        })
        onClose();
    }

    return (
        <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onRequestClose={onClose}>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <input placeholder='Tytuł' value={title} onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)} />

                <div>
                    <Label>Start Date</Label>
                    <Datetime value={start} onChange={date => setStart(date)} />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <Label>End Date</Label>
                    <Datetime value={end} onChange={date => setEnd(date)} />
                </div>

                <Button>Dodaj Wizytę</Button>
            </form>

        </Modal>
```

Function used to open the modal through OnClick method:

```
 const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
```

The OnClick method which isn't working:

```
import AddEventModal from "./addEventModal"

 <Button onClick={() => setModalOpen(true)}>Dodaj Wizytę</Button>
 <AddEventModal isOpen={modalOpen} onClose={() => setModalOpen(false)} onEventAdded={(event) => onEventAdded(event)} />
```

When i've tried to console.log with OnClick method, the console returns the log so the button is working correctly, there must be something wrong with my functions.

Comment: Please post your code as text, preferably a snippet, rather than as images.

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of your code. Code is text. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please [edit] your question to remove all pictures, and include the relevant code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: Also please ensure that what you post is a [mre] of your issue, not just a big code dump.